# Execute selected ant tasks for a selected set of projects

Tags: build, ant

I have defined targets in ant for our games, e.g. clean, build-ios, build-android, deploy-ios, deploy-android, etc. Now I would like to define a new set of targets that represent our games, say game1, game2, game3.

My goal is to be able to launch ant with a set of target games and a set of target tasks so that for each selected game, each selected task is executed.

Example pseudo code: `Foreach [game1, game3]: clean, build-ios, deploy-ios`

How can I achieve this with ant? A requirement would be to define which games and which tasks are selected through targets, not to write them in a file that is altered manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subant` task is useful for situations where you have multiple subprojects that share similar structures.

In your main build.xml, define a target that rubs the desired build target on your game subdirectories, along with all of the generalized build targets.

```
<target name="deploy-all">
    <subant target="deploy">
        <dirset dir="." includes="game-*" />
    </subant>

    <echo message="All games deployed." />
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="deploy-ios,deploy-android">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name} build complete." />
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <echo message="Cleaning ${ant.project.name}" />
</target>

<target name="build-ios" depends="clean">
    <echo message="Building iOS ${ant.project.name}" />
</target>

<target name="build-android" depends="clean">
    <echo message="Building Android ${ant.project.name}" />
</target>

<target name="deploy-ios" depends="build-ios">
    <echo message="Deploying iOS ${ant.project.name}" />
</target>

<target name="deploy-android" depends="build-android">
    <echo message="Deploying Android ${ant.project.name}" />
</target>
```

Then, in the game-* subdirectories, create a simple build.xml that links back to the common one.

game-1/build.xml:

```
<project name="game-1" default="build">
    <import file="../build.xml" />

    <echo message="=== Building Game 1 ===" />
</project>
```

game-2/build.xml:

```
<project name="game-2" default="build">
    <import file="../build.xml" />

    <echo message="=== Building Game 2 ===" />
</project>
```

Edit: If your build needs to include/exclude certain subprojects based on the user's input or a pre-defined property, you can modify the `subant` task's nested resource collection to accommodate for this.

```
    <property name="game.includes" value="game-*" />
    <property name="game.excludes" value="" />

    <subant target="deploy">
        <dirset dir="." includes="${game.includes}" excludes="${game.excludes}" />
    </subant>
```

The user can then run a command that optionally passes values for `game.includes` and/or `game.excludes`. If these properties are not specified, the values defined above by the `property` task will be used as defaults.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Though I am still unable to easily select for which of the many games I want to run the tasks. If I understand your example correct, you suggest to create a subant to build all games, but my goal would be to only build selected games. I think I could create subant tasks to combine every single target and game, but that is a lot of writing. Is there an easier way to tell ant to build target "deploy", but only for selected games, not all of them? Say, select which of the subant build files I want to include, instead of including game-*..? Thanks

Comment: Subant iterates over a resource collection (in this case a set of directories), so if you want to be selective about which subprojects you build, you can use that resource collection's includes and excludes. I'll edit the answer to show an example.